# Laravel 8 many-to-many relation pivot fields not updating

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 8, I'm trying to update additional pivot values on a many-to-many relation between `User` and `Account` models. The `users_accounts` pivot table has additional columns for storing permissions. I'm also using a custom `AccountPermissions` pivot class for the mapping.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function accounts(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Account::class, 'users_accounts', 'user_uid', 'account_uid')
            ->withPivot('_view', '_create', '_edit', '_delete', '_grant')
            ->as('permissions')
            ->using(AccountPermissions::class);;
    }
}
```

(I know the db column names are rubbish, I didn't design the schema...)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Account extends Model
{

    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_accounts', 'account_uid', 'user_uid')
            ->withPivot('_view', '_create', '_edit', '_delete', '_grant')
            ->as('permissions')
            ->using(AccountPermissions::class);
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class AccountPermissions extends Pivot
{
    public $table = 'users_accounts';
    public $primaryKey = 'users_account_uid';
}
```

I'm calling the following method to save the permissions (inside a Livewire component):

```
public function savePermissions(User $user, $permissions, $accountId)
{
    $user->accounts()->syncWithPivotValues([$accountId], $permissions, false);
}
```

Where `$permissions` parameter is an array of new values to be saved:

```
[
  '_view' => true,
  '_create' => true,
  '_edit' => true,
  '_delete' => true,
  '_grant' => false,
]
```

For some reason this is not working. The pivot values are not being updated when `savePermissions` method is invoked. I also tried several different approaches:

```
$user->accounts()->updateExistingPivot($accountId, $permissions);
```

```
$user->accounts()->sync([$accountId => $permissions], false);
```

None of them worked either.

Retrieving the relation values works just fine, just can't update them.

Comment: Have you tried to add `$user->save();` after the sync?

Comment: I did, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are the properties in the `$fillable` array?

Comment: That was it. I assumed it wasn't necessary because the `Pivot` class has the `$guarded` attribute set to an empty array by default, but apparently I was wrong.